# print cmakelist variable

Tags: cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I print the contents of a variable in CMakelists

eg: link_directories(${ZED_LIBRARY_DIR})

I want to print ZED_LIBRARY_DIR

I tried

MESSAGE( STATUS "xxxx:"   ${ZED_INCLUDE_DIRS})

but get no output, thank you for help. I can not seem to find documentation that talks about doing this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226009/print-cmakelist-variable/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2016-02-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got around this by passing  -d option on catkin_make and grepping for output.

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2016-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JohnDoe](https://answers.ros.org/users/92256/johndoe/) on 2023-07-28**:
Hi! Do you know the option to print the message with `catkin build`?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my case (using colcon), in addition to changing the log level to debug (via `colcon --log-level=debug build`), I had to also change the message from `STATUS` to `WARNING` before my message appeared.

In order to grep, make sure you redirect the output from stderr to stdout (`colcon --log-level=debug build 2>&1`)

---

Originally posted by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) with karma: 1083 on 2020-06-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1